# Why would the static method Thread.interrupted clear the interrupt status, which is a non-static field?

Tags: java, concurrency

I'm reading [the interrupt section of the java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html). In the bottom of this article, there is this paragraph.

> The interrupt mechanism is implemented using an internal flag known as the interrupt status. Invoking `Thread.interrupt` sets this flag. **When a thread checks for an interrupt by invoking the static method `Thread.interrupted`, interrupt status is cleared.** The non-static `isInterrupted` method, which is used by one thread to query the interrupt status of another, does not change the interrupt status flag.

Since `Thread.interrupted` is a static method, how could it clear the interrupt status, which is a non-static field.

I read the source code of the staic method Thread.interrupted(). That didn't help to solve this question.

Comment: `Thread.interrupted()` reads and clears the status of _the current thread._ Although it literally is a `static` method, it only ever acts on a particular `Thread` instance. As for how it's possible, I don't know, but it can't be any harder than if it called `Thread.currentThread()` to get the instance. As for the reason why, I don't know, but there are several aspects of Java threads, dating back to the very first published version of Java, that IMO, were not very well thought out.

Comment: P.S., Don't get me started on why they call it "currentThread()."

Answer (score 2):

Why didn't the [source code](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/lang/Thread.java#L959) solve this question? The JavaDoc is pretty clear about it in the 4 relevant methods:

- static `currentThread()`
- static `interrupted()`
- `isInterrupted()`
- native `isInterrupted(boolean)`

```
/**
 * Returns a reference to the currently executing thread object.
 *
 * @return  the currently executing thread.
 */
public static native Thread currentThread();

/**
 * Tests whether the current thread has been interrupted.  The
 * <i>interrupted status</i> of the thread is cleared by this method.  In
 * other words, if this method were to be called twice in succession, the
 * second call would return false (unless the current thread were
 * interrupted again, after the first call had cleared its interrupted
 * status and before the second call had examined it).
 *
 * <p>A thread interruption ignored because a thread was not alive
 * at the time of the interrupt will be reflected by this method
 * returning false.
 *
 * @return  <code>true</code> if the current thread has been interrupted;
 *          <code>false</code> otherwise.
 * @see #isInterrupted()
 * @revised 6.0
 */
public static boolean interrupted() {
    return currentThread().isInterrupted(true);
}

/**
 * Tests whether this thread has been interrupted.  The <i>interrupted
 * status</i> of the thread is unaffected by this method.
 *
 * <p>A thread interruption ignored because a thread was not alive
 * at the time of the interrupt will be reflected by this method
 * returning false.
 *
 * @return  <code>true</code> if this thread has been interrupted;
 *          <code>false</code> otherwise.
 * @see     #interrupted()
 * @revised 6.0
 */
public boolean isInterrupted() {
    return isInterrupted(false);
}

/**
 * Tests if some Thread has been interrupted.  The interrupted state
 * is reset or not based on the value of ClearInterrupted that is
 * passed.
 */
private native boolean isInterrupted(boolean ClearInterrupted);
```

Static `Thread#interrupted` calls non-static `Thread#isInterrupted(boolean)` with `true` (i.e. "reset the interrupted state, see JavaDoc of the native method declaration). The current thread instance is obtained via static method `Thread#currentThread()`

`java.lang.Thread` does not have a field `interrupted`, since the interrupt state of the thread is maintained by the JVM/OS.